# Summarize array of objects by common property (date)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi i am having an angular project .

Currently I am having an  array named historyArr . it has some statistics data for 2 days as below.

```
 [
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T16:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 20,
    "delivered": 5,
    "undeliverable": 5,
    "expired": 5,
    "enroute": 5
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T17:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 50,
    "delivered": 10,
    "undeliverable": 15,
    "expired": 10,
    "enroute": 15
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T18:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 8,
    "delivered": 2,
    "undeliverable": 2,
    "expired": 2,
    "enroute": 2
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 160,
    "delivered": 40,
    "undeliverable": 40,
    "expired": 40,
    "enroute": 40
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-02T01:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 200,
    "delivered": 50,
    "undeliverable": 50,
    "expired": 50,
    "enroute": 50
  }
]
```

I want to reduce the above array , so that i would like to perform the summation of statistics per day . So I want to transform the above array to the one below. I am a free to use moment.js libaries for parsing dates.

```
[
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01",
    "total": 78,
    "delivered": 17,
    "undeliverable": 22,
    "expired": 17,
    "enroute": 22
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-02",
    "total": 360,
    "delivered": 90,
    "undeliverable": 90,
    "expired": 90,
    "enroute": 900
  }
]
```

i know its a difficult question. the project is uploaded in stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqmdpy

https://angular-zqmdpy.stackblitz.io

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqmdpy?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

really appreciate any help
thank you

Comment: could you post the codes you already tried?

Comment: I dont have the code , but i know the logic , but no idea how can implement it . :( because not sure about the typescript code.  my logic is iterate through each item in the array transform the date "2020-07-01T16:00:00.000+0000" to like this 2020-07-01 using moment js libraries , then in the new array performs a summation . But i dont know how can i achieve using typescript. let me see if i can do an attempt .wait

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may

- do [`String.prototype.slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) to obtain meaningful portion of `dateRange` and use that as a key
- to traverse your source array (e.g. with [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce))
- and build up the [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/Map) having grouped/summarized objects as respective value,
- then extract those values into array with [`Map.prototype.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/values)
- ***assuming all properties, other than `dateRange` should get summed up***, you may use slight shortcut not to hardcode all of them explicitly:

```js
const src = [{"dateRange":"2020-07-01T16:00:00.000+0000","total":20,"delivered":5,"undeliverable":5,"expired":5,"enroute":5},{"dateRange":"2020-07-01T17:00:00.000+0000","total":50,"delivered":10,"undeliverable":15,"expired":10,"enroute":15},{"dateRange":"2020-07-01T18:00:00.000+0000","total":8,"delivered":2,"undeliverable":2,"expired":2,"enroute":2},{"dateRange":"2020-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000","total":160,"delivered":40,"undeliverable":40,"expired":40,"enroute":40},{"dateRange":"2020-07-02T01:00:00.000+0000","total":200,"delivered":50,"undeliverable":50,"expired":50,"enroute":50}],

      result = [...src
        .reduce((acc, o) => {
          const key = o.dateRange.slice(0,10),
                group = acc.get(key)
          if(group){
            const { dateRange, ...rest } = o
            Object
              .keys(rest)
              .forEach(key => 
                group[key] = (group[key] || 0) + (o[key] || 0))
          } else {
            acc.set(key, {...o, dateRange: key})
          }          
          return acc
        }, new Map)
        .values()
     ]
     
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: Type 'IterableIterator<any>' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569) but i am getting this error when i use code in my project.

Comment: @knowledgeseeker001 : try `result = Array.from(src.reduce(..).values())

Comment: Hi Yevgen I am bit confused . could you post they answer on this new question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63339507/typscript-error-happening-type-iterableiteratorany-is-not-an-array-type-or

Answer (score 2):

This is an idea how you should do it, I'm not taking care at all of the Correct format for the date, you should improve it, I created an auxiliar arr that doesnt mutate in order to not change the original array.

```
    ngOnInit() {
    var temp = {};
    var obj = null;
    
  this.arr = data;
  this.historyArr = this.arr['histogramDistributionbyCdrStatuses']; 
  this.historyArr.forEach(el=>{
      el.dateRange=moment(el.dateRange).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
  })
  let auxArr = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.historyArr));

  for(var i=0; i < auxArr.length; i++) {
      obj=auxArr[i];

      if(!temp[obj.dateRange]) {
          temp[obj.dateRange] = obj;
      } else {
          temp[obj.dateRange].total += obj.total;
      }
    }
    var result = [];
    for (var prop in temp)
        result.push(temp[prop]);
    console.log(result)



  }
```

Comment: The only reason above post got 2 upvotes is that author ***didn't*** post live-snippet and upvoters were lazy to at least read it through. If they would, following would be obvious: 1. the code **won't work** (it summarizes only `total` values, ignoring the rest); 2. the code is messy - it mutates input data and ***after that*** deep clones that (in suboptimal way - author would better use lodash for deep cloning, than moment for date formatting); 3. the code [fails](https://codepen.io/ygorbunkov/pen/gOrpayg?editors=0010) to deliver expected result if either property is missing for some object

Comment: ...4. and of course, this code [is slow, slow, slow](https://jsbench.me/77kdm9jgf6/1)

Answer (score 2):

I iterate over the array and get the date from an entry. I look if this date is in the help-array index. If no than I create a new entry with the properties from the entry and append it to the result. Otherwise I look with this index in my result-array and sum upevery prperty of my element to this entry.

```js
function transformArray( array ) {
    let result = [];
    let index = [];
    array.forEach(obj => {
        const  PROPERTIES = Object.keys(obj);
        PROPERTIES.splice(PROPERTIES.indexOf('dateRange'),1);
        let dat = obj.dateRange.substr(0,10);
        let resIndex = index.indexOf(dat);
        if ( resIndex == -1) {
            index.push(dat);
            let entry = { dateRange: dat}
            PROPERTIES.forEach (prop => entry[prop] = obj[prop] || 0);
            result.push(entry);
        } else {
            let entry = result[resIndex];
            PROPERTIES.forEach (prop => entry[prop] = (entry[prop] || 0) + (obj[prop] || 0));
        }
    });
    return result;
}

let historyArr = [
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T16:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 20,
    "delivered": 5,
    "undeliverable": 5,
    "expired": 5,
    "enroute": 5
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T17:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 50,
    "delivered": 10,
    "undeliverable": 15,
    "expired": 10,
    "enroute": 15
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-01T18:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 8,
    "delivered": 2,
    "undeliverable": 2,
    "expired": 2,
    "enroute": 2
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-02T00:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 160,
    "delivered": 40,
    "undeliverable": 40,
    "expired": 40,
    "enroute": 40
  },
  {
    "dateRange": "2020-07-02T01:00:00.000+0000",
    "total": 200,
    "delivered": 50,
    "undeliverable": 50,
    "expired": 50,
    "enroute": 50
  }
];

console.log(transformArray(historyArr));
```

Comment: @Yevgen Gorbunkov You are right, I changed my code for this. In real life for work I consider these cases but here we normally only show the OP the way or a solution but we can't look for all cases which could be happen. For this had the programmer for himself to look, espacially we don't know all circumstances. Thanks for your advice.