# Typscript error happening . Type 'IterableIterator<any>' is not an array type or a string type.)

Tags: javascript, typescript

Hi I am having an angular project and I have an error which i can see in the vss code.
Not sure how i can fix this.

```
    Type 'IterableIterator<any>' is not an array type or a string type.
 Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.ts(2569)
```

Here is the code snippet

```
  aggregator(data: HistogramDistribution[]) {
   data.forEach(
      item => {
       item.dateRange =  moment.utc(item.dateRange).local().format("YYYY-MM-DD").toString();
      }
    );
 
    return [...data
      .reduce((acc, o) => {
        
        const key = o.dateRange,
              group = acc.get(key)
        group ?
        (group.total += o.total, 
        group.delivered += o.delivered, 
        group.undeliverable += o.undeliverable,
        group.expired += o.expired,
        group.enroute += o.enroute) :
        acc.set(key, {...o, dateRange: key})
        return acc
      }, new Map)
      .values()
   ];
  }
```

I have tried to add     "downlevelIteration": true to my tsconfig.json . but still the error persists.

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
    "lib": ["es2017", "dom"],
    "downlevelIteration": true
  }
}
```

Appreciate if you can throw some help .

thank you

Comment: You [may use](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fqpshc) `Array.from()` to turn iterator (returned by `Map.prototype.values()`) into array.

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: See section [Relation with Array objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in the MDN documentation.

Comment: Basics: `Map`s are not arrays.

Comment: The error you're referring to is likely caused by the way `Map` values are turned into array (spread syntax), so you can use an alternative method (based on `Array.from()`). You may try the code from [my snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fqpshc) in your project and that error should be gone.

Comment: If you're still suffering to make that work, [here's closer to the point snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2qv4z) (based on your own stackblitz project).

Answer (score 0):

Changing your compile target to `es6` or above in your `tsconfig.json` file will fix it

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015"
  }
}
```

or if you want to keep using the older version, you can enable `downLevelIteration` like this

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2015",
    "downlevelIteration": true
   }
}
```